# Were slave plantations economically superior or inferior to plantations with paid labor?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, slavery

According to certain Marxist authors (Mostly Georgi Plekhanov (and some others), but I'm afraid I cannot quote because the text is not in electronic form and not in English.), slavery in US and latter in South America did not disappear because of enlightenment and abolitionist movements ("spiritual" reasons). Instead, there were purely materialistic (technological and economic) causes that made slavery non-profitable and obsolete. This economic pressure resulted not only in abolitionist movement, but also created rift in society, big enough to cause US civil war.

My question is are there any reliable economic data about profitability of slave plantations on one side, and plantations with payed labor on other side, immediately before and after US civil war. Slave plantations certainly had advantage of unpaid labor, but also had to feed, house and clothe slaves. Also, slaves had no incentive to work harder except for fear of physical punishment. On the other hand free paid workers had to earn money to take care of themselves and their families, so they were better motivated to work harder.

**EDIT** Upon request, I will add some quotes about Marxists perspective on US civil war . This is recurring theme in Marxist literature, it basically says that slavery was obsolete, and that Southern slave owning ruling class tried to protect their vanning influence by secession. On the other hand Northern capitalist ruling class wanted to convert whole US territory to their economic model.

From Marx [himself](https://isreview.org/issue/80/karl-marx-and-american-civil-war) :

> The cultivation of the Southern export articles, cotton, tobacco, sugar, etc., carried on by slaves, is only renumerative as long as it is conducted with large gangs of slaves, on a mass scale and on wide expanses of a naturally fertile soil, which requires only simple labor. Intensive cultivation, which depends less on fertility of the soil than on investment of capital, intelligence and energy of labor, is contrary to the nature of slavery.

Also this :

> [T]he number of actual slaveholders in the South of the Union does not amount to more than 300,000, a narrow oligarchy that is confronted with many millions of so-called poor whites, whose numbers have been constantly growing through concentration of landed property and whose condition is only to be compared with that of the Roman plebeians in the period of Rome’s extreme decline. Only by acquisition and the prospect of acquisition of new Territories, as well as by filibustering expeditions [i.e. conquests of other lands, such as in Central America—ISR], is it possible to square the interests of these “poor whites” with those of the slaveholders, to give their restless thirst for action a harmless direction and to tame them with the prospect of one day becoming slaveholders themselves.
>
> **A strict confinement of slavery within its old terrain, therefore, was bound according to economic law to lead to its gradual extinction**, in the political sphere to annihilate the hegemony that the slave states exercised through the Senate, and finally to expose the slaveholding oligarchy within its own states to threatening perils from the “poor whites.” In accordance with the principle that any further extension of slave Territories was to be prohibited by law, the Republicans therefore attacked the rule of the slaveholders at its root. The Republican election victory was accordingly bound to lead to open struggle between North and South. And this election victory, as already mentioned, was itself conditioned by the split in the Democratic camp.

But Marx was also critical about motivations of Northern capitalists

> As a slave, the worker has exchange value, a value; as a free
> wage-worker he has no value; it is rather his power of
> disposing of his labor, effected by exchange with him which
> has value. It is not he who stands towards the capitalist as
> exchange value, but the capitalist towards him. His
> valuelessness and devaluation is the presupposition of capital
> precondition of free labor in general.27
> In slave-labor, even that part of the working-day in which
> the slave is only replacing the value of his own means of
> existence, in which, therefore, in fact, he works for himself
> alone, appears as labor for his master. **All the slave's labor
> appears as unpaid labor. In wage-labor, on the contrary,
> even surplus labor, or unpaid labor, appears as paid**. There
> the property-relation conceals the labor of the slave for
> himself; here the money-relation conceals the unrequited labor
> of the wage-laborer.28

Finally, even [today](https://medium.com/refuse-to-cooperate/the-american-civil-war-1854-1876-a-marxist-perspective-2703d5010406) socialists and left-leaning authors then to hold US civil war as a conflict between ruling classes primarily concerned about profit, not ethics:

> From a Marxist perspective, here is the true cause of the main stage of the American Civil War. **The Union, or the North, had developed an economy based on wage slavery; whereas, the Confederacy, or the South, had retained chattel slavery.** These two economic system were both subdivisions of Capitalist economics, or the private ownership of the means of production. **Theoretically, it is impossible for these two subsystems to coexist peacefully in any economy**; so, an ultimate conflict to determine the future of capitalist production was inevitable. The remainder of the circumstances are naturally absorbed by this reality.

Comment: '_According to certain Marxist authors_' ...? It's generally better to actually name one or more specific authors (and ideally cite them using a quote from one or more of their works to support the assertion).

Comment: @sempaiscuba Mostly Georgi Plekhanov (and some others), but I'm afraid I cannot quote because the text is not in electronic form and not in English.

Comment: @rs.29 so you have the only printed copy and no-one else can do a translation .... post the correct references...

Comment: I decided to forgo Plekhanov because I found some quotes from Marx himself. Basically, it all goes to the same conclusion that slavery was economically obsolete, and that Northern capitalist wanted to introduce their system to the South .

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Yes, I have found tons of studies clamming that slavery was profitable (no surprise there) , although as you can see from the links I added Marx claimed otherwise. I'm actually interested in comparison of  profitability between slave based plantations, and plantations with payed labor.

Comment: "Economically superior" is not the same thing as "profitable." In an economically superior social system, investments give high returns, GDP grows rapidly, and everybody gets exponentially fatter and happier. The profitability of a plantation only measures whether the owner of the plantation is getting a high return. As a simpler example, we could measure whether burglary is profitable -- it probably does give a high return on investment. But that doesn't mean that a society prospers if everyone turns to burglary. Workers paid in cash go out and buy things, which is good for the economy.

Comment: @BenCrowell You have 1 plantation and x slaves. After all costs are subtracted (like slave upkeep, cost of seeds etc ...) is there any profit left and how much is it ? Then take same plantation and y hired hands (those needed to effectively replace slaves) . Again calculate the profits and compare with previous case.

Comment: @rs.29: You seem to be providing a clarification of your definition of the question. I wasn't complaining about the clarity of the question. I was complaining that it's the wrong question to ask. It can be simultaneously true that (a) a slave labor system is more profitable for the owner than a wage labor system, and (b) a slave labor system is economically inferior to a wage labor system.

Comment: @BenCrowell I would disagree, after all even in this age owners of the company mostly care about their own profit, not about some metaphysical "good of society". My question is simple: you have Mr Evil Bastard as plantation owner, he is not for or against slavery, he only cares about profit. What system (slavery system as before civil war , or wage system as after the war ) would benefit more his goal to earn more money ?

Comment: Marx wasn't the only one. Adam Smith said in The Wealth Of Nations (18th century), "The experience of all ages and nations, I believe, demonstrates that the work done by slaves, though it appears to cost only their maintenance, is in the end the dearest [costliest] of any." You can read his full reasoning here: https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/3300/pg3300-images.html

Answer (score 3):

The Romans (well, a few stoic philosophers at least) already knew slavery was economically unsound. A slave needs to be housed, cared for, fed, medicated and supervised. Also during the hours the slave doesn't work. (Being sick, sleeping or whatever.) No matter if you manage them poorly or generously. Nobody likes to be a slave, it's quite common to work as little as possible. Hence the myth of lazy and stupid Africans. They weren't lazy or stupid, but appearing that way saved them a few lashes.

Hiring non slaves is initially more expensive, but you don't have to pay for housing, caring, feeding and medicating. You do have to supervise your employees, but no where near the level you need for slaves. You only pay them for the time you use them. How to keep themselves alive is their problem.

I agree that a lot depends on specific circumstances, but compare it with a modern taxi. Per km driven far more expensive than owning a car. If you consider all costs of a car (parking in a garage, insurance, maintenance, etc.) it's cheaper than owning a car. You only pay per km you actually are driven.

Comment: Depends in large part on how you treat the slaves, what you use them for, etc. etc. And of course on the scarcity of free labour, especially CHEAP free labour.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me that a taxi is cheaper than a car in all circumstances. I think it works only if you live in a city (where both parking space is more expensive and the distances are smaller)

Comment: The general reasonment in this answer makes sense, but it doesn't address the slaves- or free workers- plantations in the US nor provides data for comparing their rentability.

Comment: "Hiring non slaves is initially more expensive," depending on how the slave was acquired, it would probably be much more expensive initially to have slave labor. Slaves in the US antebellum period peaked around 1860 and each was about the price of a car today.

Comment: This answer suffers from poor logic on a couple of fronts.  1) how does appearing lazy save you from lashes?  2) hiring workers is less expensive, up front, than buying a slave.  3) what does ride sharing have to do with slavery?  If it's fixed vs. variable costs, see number 2.  4) Roman slavery was quite different than North American Slavery.  For instance, it was not based on race.  Lastly, if slavery wasn't profitable, it wouldn't have survived for so long in so many places.  In the American south, slavery was so profitable that war was preferable to ending it (racism notwithstanding).

Comment: The original problem in America was the lack of population that one could hire: so your argument about hiring non-slaves is not as trivial as you like to show it.

Comment: If you don’t pay enough to support themselves, they would move somewhere else or just die out. If they do this during harvest season, you would be ruined economically. And speaking about modern taxi: commuting to work modest 20 miles one-way would cost you $20-30K per year. You might don’t need a car if you live and work in NYC, but we are talking about America, don’t we?

Comment: This answer would benefit from citing sources and in general from giving evidence for the claims it makes.

Answer (score 3):

***“My question is are there any reliable economic data about profitability of slave plantations on one side, and plantations with payed labor on other side, immediately before and after US civil war”***

I don’t think there are some direct data to compare, because slave plantations ceased to exist immediately after Civil War, and I am not aware of significant number of plantations with payed labor before Civil War .
However, **I think that in general antebellum South slave plantations were more profitable** - otherwise planters would sell or free majority of their slaves and hire laborers (who could be the same former slaves).

Generally speaking, slave labor could be more profitable comparing with other types of labor within some technology level boundaries. It is not profitable to own slaves  if they can not produce significantly more than they consume themselves; it could be more profitable to hire skilled worker to operate complicated machinery than invest in training of the slave. In between, slavery could be more profitable than alternative. By the mid-XIX century technology was high enough to make payed labor more profitable. However, the were some loopholes, and the huge one was raw cotton production in US South after cotton gin introduction.

According to *“Time on the Cross: The Economics of American Negro Slavery “ by Robert Fogel (Nobel Laureate in economics) and Stanley Engerman*, **South plantations were about 20-30% more profitable than free labor farms on both North and South** (don’t have this book on hand and can not quote exect pages and numbers).

Antebellum plantation slave labor profitability depended on specific crop, on market demand, and on market competition. It is why **american raw cotton dominated world market and constituted huge majority of US exports, while american raw sugar was predominantly consumed on the South, could not compete with better and less expensive caribbean sugar on international market, and was barely profitable only due to protectionists 24% tariffs**.

***“Federal protection was a lifeline for an industry that could not openly compete with its rivals in the Caribbean. The sugar duty guaranteed reasonably good profits of 6 to 12 percent and offset the notoriously heavy cost of cane sugar production”***
*The Fair Trade Fraud, by James Bovard, NY 1991, ISBN 0-312-06193-5, Page 71*

It is due to high cotton profitability planters sometimes preferred to buy other agriculture products from North rather than divert slave labor and soil:

***“the chief articles imported are bacon and mules from the Northern States. The only article sold is cotton”***
*North America, its agriculture and climate, by Robert Russell, Edinburgh 1857, p. 289-291*

It is because cotton profitability due to huge demand by industrial development, Southern morality turned from labeling slavery as necessary evil to praising it as positive good. It is why three biggest US protestant denominations were split on southern and northern branches between cotton gin introduction and secession.
***“The prevailing ideas entertained by him (Thomas Jefferson) and most of the leading statesmen at the time of the formation of the old constitution, were that the enslavement of the African was in violation of the laws of nature; that it was wrong in principle, socially, morally, and politically. It was an evil they knew not well how to deal with, but the general opinion of the men of that day was that, somehow or other in the order of Providence, the institution would be evanescent and pass away. This idea, though not incorporated in the constitution, was the prevailing idea at that time... Those ideas, however, were fundamentally wrong”*** 
*Alexander H. Stephens, “Cornerсtone Speech", March 21, 1861*

***“Finally, even today socialists and left-leaning authors then to hold US civil war as a conflict between ruling classes primarily concerned about profit, not ethics:
From a Marxist perspective, here is the true cause of the main stage of the American Civil War. The Union, or the North, had developed an economy based on wage slavery; whereas, the Confederacy, or the South, had retained chattel slavery. These two economic system were both subdivisions of Capitalist economics, or the private ownership of the means of production. Theoretically, it is impossible for these two subsystems to coexist peacefully in any economy; so, an ultimate conflict to determine the future of capitalist production was inevitable”***

I don't think this is correct. Conflict was not about profit: slave South and manufacturing North were mutually profitable, and could still profitable until demand on cotton was high and cotton harvesting was not mechanized (both middle of XX century)**. So from economics point of view, they could coexist peacefully for a long time. The problem was political:  most ambitious southerners wanted to control not just their plantations, but whole country, and it did not work anymore.

** Table 3, pages 6-8, of following source
http://www2.census.gov/prod2/decennial/documents/17862820-1969ch01.pdf
https://livinghistoryfarm.org/farminginthe50s/machines_15.html

**UPDATE** After reading comments, I would like to clarify the last point of my answer, that the immediate problem planters were going to solve by trying to expand slavery and by subsequent secession was not economical but mostly political. **In 1787, they did not want to join the Union until 2/3 clause granted them preferential treatment in House and presidential elections. By 1860 all this was lost, so they did not want to stay in the same Union being hopeless minority in all branches of government.** It is why they insisted on slavery expantion to territories, hoping that new slave states would give them if not majority, but at least parity in Senate.

Comment: Good answer, although I'm not sure why comparison between profitability of same plantation(s) before and after the war could not be made. They presumably had similar level of technology, same crop (cotton) , maybe even same workers (former slaves now as paid labor) . Also, if slavery was so profitable, why would slavers want to expand it to other territories (new states) ? They could just keep status quo in existing slave states and reap profits.

Comment: @rs.29 To estimate plantation profitability, you just need planter’s expenses and income. With sharecropping, you need expenses and income not just landowner, but all sharecroppers as well; this is much more complicated, and some info could be not possible to get. “why would slavers want to expand it to other territories (new states) ?” As I said, they wanted to keep controlling the country, and only way to do it was to have more senators in US Congress, so they wanted more slave states.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in sharecroppers profit, I'm only interested in profit of land owner, i.e. would slave owning be more profitable for him then hiring labor (or sharecropping) . As for your argument, I don't think slave owners would push for secession so violently if they were profitable in existing slave states. After all, before the war no serious politician (including Lincoln) proposed complete ban on slavery throughout entire US, including "old" slave states.

Comment: @rs.29 see Update for clarification why slave owners pushed for slavery expansion and secession if they were profitable in existing slave states. As of comparing slave vs hiring labor profitability, good starting point would be “Time on the Cross" reading. However, ignoring that half century increase of cotton demand and production did not produce noticeable successful attempts to replace slave plantation with hired labor would not make any answer more convincing.

Comment: You still didn't explain why slave owners didn't want to remain minority in government, and why did they go for such desperate gamble as succession, if they could profit in existing slave states, and if institution of slavery was not jeopardized in those states.

Comment: @rs.29 various reasons. Some (like Alexander Stephens) voted against secession, but yield to  majority (39% voted against secession in Alabama, 30% - in Georgia, four Confederacy states originally rejected secession but switched side when war started). Majority believed North would not hold them in Union and did not see secession as desperate gamble. Many felt hopeless minority would ultimately jeopardize slavery. Some most active (William Yancey and “father of secession” Robert Rhett) see secession as opportunity to advance their political carrier and tricked majority to secession

Comment: @rs.29 Now it is your turn: you did not explain why hired labor plantations did not replace slave if former were more profitable.

Comment: I think the reasons were more based on culture and certain fears, then economics. Most of slave owners didn't know how could they run plantations with free (mostly Black) laborers. They had their way of life and wanted to protect it . Also, there was a fear that large masses of free Blacks would basically rape White women and kill White children (original reason for formation of KKK after the war), just like they did in slave rebellions (for example in Nat Turner’s Rebellion, 1831)

Comment: @rs.29 It does not take most - as soon few would be successful, more would follow. It might not kill slavery completely, but at least we would know about this practice. And for the start, it did not take freeing slaves - most population on the South were hard working non-slave owning whites, some were hired as farm laborers. When Jane Davis, father of future Confederacy president, moved his family south (what is now LA and MS), he sold his farm and purchased additional slaves, because slave price were lower in Kentucky. He could hire paid laborer instead, if it were more profitable.

Comment: @rs.29 BTW, speaking on “based on culture” - please accept it as one additional reason why slave owners didn't want to remain minority in government. It was based on their culture - as already I pointed, they did not want to enter the Union being designated minority in government.

Comment: I don't think it was possible to hire free Blacks as laborers in slave states. Most Blacks who were freed (for example by the their masters) fled North because there was a constant threat they would be enslaved again . Southerns simply didn't want free Blacks around. For a change there would had to be substantial number of Black freedman to hire, and that didn't happen. As for poor Whites, they usually tried to run their own farms. It would be interesting to know did anyone tried to hire poor Whites as cotton pickers .

Comment: @rs.29 In 1860, there were more free blacks in the South than in the North - 250,787 vs 225,961 . As for poor farmless Whites, they would do what is more profitable for them. They would work for planters to earn money to buy own farm - if planters would pay high enough. The problem was - planters did not need to pay high enough, because for them slave labor was more profitable. When slavery was dead after the war, planters were forced to hire paid laborers, and millions of whites worked on former plantations as tenants or sharecroppers.

Comment: "Southerners came to believe that the only successful means of removing the threat of free Negroes was to expel them from the southern states or to change their status from free persons to ... slaves."[34]:112 Free Negroes were perceived as "an evil of no ordinary magnitude"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Negro#Free_negroes_unwelcome

Comment: @rs.29 I would not jump to the conclusion based solely on Wiki articles; sometimes they demonstrate gross ignorance or outright lie. Specifically this one states that “During the nineteenth century, the number and proportion of population of free blacks in the South shrank”, while according to census data, this number is actually quadrupled, from 61,575 in 1800 to 250,787 in 1860 www.ncpedia.org/sites/default/files/census_stats_1790-1860.pdf And more important, it is nothing to do with the question, why planters could not hire white laborers before slavery was abolished.

Comment: You fail to point out that most of the Southern free Blacks resided in states like Maryland or Delaware, that remained in the Union. Compare that with states like Georgia or South Carolina, where number of free Blacks remained low despite overall increase in population. Also, most of free Blacks were actually people who were mulattoes, or even quadroons, and appeared reasonably European, yet they were still Black for purpose of census. Overall, it is not just this Wiki article, other sources point out increased difficulties for free Blacks in the south as war draw nearer.

Comment: @rs.29 You fail to point out how all this (especially that most free Black were mulattoes) can explain why planters did hire white laborers and paid slave traders if slave plantations were economically inferior to plantations with paid labor. Are we still trying to answer your original questions, or you just switching the subject because you don’t want to admit that answer you don’t like is most likely correct? If some different questions came to your mind during this discussion, just place new question, I would be glad to answer if I can.

Comment: @rs.29 BTW, you reference to Plekhanov makes me guess you speak Russian. If this is correct, I can give  links to my  articles in Russian on American Civil War. My sources are in English  - I live in USA since the last century, and using not just books from libraries, but on some instances archive materials as well.

Comment: As I said before, I think that slave owning planters didn't want cheap hired labor competition. Therefore, they acted against free Blacks, and poor Whites usually avoided cotton picking if they cold (it was "job for Blacks"). To put it simply, Southern culture prevented development of economy based on wages . Yes, I'm still interested in profits in both cases (wage labor and slavery) . Any links would be appreciated .

Comment: @rs.29 If hired labor were cheap enough planters would just hire laborers instead of buying slaves. Because it did not happened, we can conclude that slave labor was more profitable for planters. As soon slave labor became unavailable, planters were forced to use hired labor, and there were more post-bellum white than black cotton sharecroppers. Link to start http://7iskusstv.com/2015/Nomer7/Barhavin1.php click on my name on the heading would bring you to the list of my articles most of them on Civil War. I suggest you read comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

In this course taught by David Blight, he explains that slavery was extremely profitable.

EDIT
Per comments, Blight explains that slavery was profitable enough to warrant, among other things: 1) a free soil political movement in the North and 2) a willingness, in the South, to secede from from the Union and engage in a brutal civil war.

I don’t remember the micro economics of plantations, but slaves were valuable. This value derived from their economic value (as opposed to simply luxury or status).

https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/the-civil-war-and-reconstruction-era-1845-1877/id733019681

Comment: Good link, but I'm mostly interested in comparison of profitability .

Comment: I've listened to that podcast/course several times over the last couple of years. It's really good.

Comment: Answers on stackexchange are generally expected to be self-contained. This is just a link, not an answer. How about summarizing what you learned from this podcast?